# How to pass parameter on submit button in wordpress / php?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I have a common popup contact form at three different places in a one page wordpress website. Now the issue is that I can't identify from which button the form is sent. I have used easy modal plugin and the form is a normal bootstrap form. How can I identify this? is there something i can do with hidden fields or how? any help is appreciated . Thanks

Answer (score 1):

'is there something i can do with hidden fields or how?' - Yes there is:

```
<form>
    <!-- other input fields -->
    <input type="hidden" name="form-id" value="form1">
</form>
```

On the server side you can get it the same way you get your other variables:

```
$form = $_GET["form-id"];
//or
$form = $_POST["form-id"];
```

In a comment you said you are new to this. Have a look at [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Forms), it might be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
<form action="action.php">
  Email: <input type="text" name="name"><br>
  <input type="hidden" name="from" value="topModal">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Change the value of `topModal` to any other word to identify the request of origin.

Answer (score -1):

You can send hidden field in the form to distinguish them all from each other.

Comment: How do i do this?? can you setup a fiddle or something? sorry i am new to this

Comment: In all your forms just add a new input field. Like : <input type="hidden" name="myhiddenfield" /> Change the names in all forms of the hidden field and use this filed on server side to distinguish the forms.

Comment: there is only 1 common form that is being used